# How To Put Different Details in Details Section in Crystal Report?

Tags: c#, sql, crystal-reports

Welcome Guys, I Have  Problem with Crystal Report!My database are order/customer database

I have two tables :
 first table

```
   ## Order ##

id   Date     Customer_id
```

Second table

```
  ## Order_Details ##

order_Id   Product_Id    Sealed_Items
```

Here is the problem, I build my report on Stored Procedures. I want my report to view each order with its Products List but I do not know how to put their fields in Details Section 
I tried  Groubing but I failed.

Can Any Body Help Me?

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/499498/Creating-a-simple-but-useful-Crystal-Report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link both tables with `id` and `order_Id` and create a group using `order_ID`. Now place the products in detail section.

Comment: What do you mean by link table??? if you mean to link them in database ,i have already linked two table in database by join relation, or you mean to link between to stored proc in Visual         and how to groub two stored procedures together        Thanks in advance

Comment: I doesn't mean any operation on database. I am purely talking in CR prespective. Linking means when you add tables in CR you get a link tab, Link tables there and grouping means after linking is done then on report desing part group the fields.

Comment: I am sorry , i know i exhausted you ,but can you explain with example  thanks in advance

Comment: there is nothing complicated here... once you tool tables in the crystal report and go to **link**  tab there link the tables as explained in my answer. now clicl ok , So you are on design now.. in desing do as explained in answer

Comment: Solved Thanks for Your Effort Siva ^_^